# How to calculate time sessions on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, session, aggregate

I have a situation:

I have data stored into a mongodb collection (called logwebs) of mongodb with the following structure:

account     access_time profile_id  and so on

This collection stored logs from users navigation behind a proxy, so it is a lot of data

I need to group by account and access_time but sorted by access_time too

```
{ account: "aaaa", access_time: "2020-04-04 12:27:00" }     //First Session
{ account: "aaaa", access_time: "2020-04-04 12:30:21" }     
{ account: "aaaa", access_time: "2020-04-04 12:31:20" }     //Ends of First session

{ account: "aaaa", access_time: "2020-04-04 12:40:20" }     //Second Session
{ account: "aaaa", access_time: "2020-04-04 12:41:25" }
{ account: "aaaa", access_time: "2020-04-04 12:42:30" }     //Ends of Second session
```

How I can get sessions for every user. Sessions are calculated like this:

When a user request the first request, I create the first session,

When the session ends?

If the next access_time log isn't greater than 5 minutes, I have to take the next log as the current log and repeat the process, I store the first access_time log to calculate the total tima of session.

When the next access_time log is greater, the session ends with a calculated time = current access_time log (NOT CURRENT + 1 ACCESS_TIME LOG) - first access_log time

I need any way to calculate this on mongodb pipeline or other way because from php I tried some ways but isn't good by memory and so on.

Comment: Why do you consider `"2020-04-04 12:42:30"` as "end of Second session"? Another access may come afterwards.

Comment: Is an example, if you see the next group of logs, the first time is greater than it by 5 minutes.

Comment: It's a session of user navigation, I take a sit, I surf by google requesting x requests, I take a break for 10 minutes, I combat for surf again. Here there are two navigation sessions. The idea is calculate the navigation time for users.

Answer (score 0):

The following aggregation calculates the *sessions* and returns session *start* and *end* times (for each session). Note that I converted the string `access_time` field to a `date` object for making the calculations simpler.

```
const FIVE_MINS = 5 * 60 * 1000    // time in milliseconds

db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $sort: { account: 1, access_time: 1 } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "$account", 
          access_times: { $push: { $toDate: "$access_time" } } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          sessions: { 
              $reduce: { 
                   input: "$access_times", 
                   initialValue: { 
                       first: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$access_times", 0 ] },
                       prev: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$access_times", 0 ] },
                       sessions: []
                   },
                   in: {
                       $cond: [ { $gt: [ { $subtract: [ "$$this", "$$value.prev" ] }, FIVE_MINS ] },
                                { 
                                   first: "$$this", 
                                   prev: "$$this",
                                   sessions: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value.sessions" , 
                                                                [ { start: "$$value.first", end: "$$value.prev" } ] 
                                              ] } 
                                 },
                                 { 
                                    first: "$$value.first", 
                                    prev: "$$this", 
                                    sessions: "$$value.sessions" 
                                 }
                       ]
                   }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $project: {
          _id: 0,
          account: "$_id",
          access_times: 1,
          sessions: { 
              $concatArrays: [ "$sessions.sessions", [ { start: "$sessions.first", end: "$sessions.prev" } ] ] 
          }
      } 
  }
] )
```

The output (using the posted data):

```
{
        "access_times" : [
                ISODate("2020-04-04T12:27:00Z"),
                ISODate("2020-04-04T12:30:21Z"),
                ISODate("2020-04-04T12:31:20Z"),
                ISODate("2020-04-04T12:40:20Z"),
                ISODate("2020-04-04T12:41:25Z"),
                ISODate("2020-04-04T12:42:30Z")
        ],
        "account" : "aaaa",
        "sessions" : [
                {
                        "start" : ISODate("2020-04-04T12:27:00Z"),
                        "end" : ISODate("2020-04-04T12:31:20Z")
                },
                {
                        "start" : ISODate("2020-04-04T12:40:20Z"),
                        "end" : ISODate("2020-04-04T12:42:30Z")
                }
        ]
}
```